# How to create an assertion in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql

I'm using `Postgresql` and `JDBC` and I'm trying to figure out how to create an assertion.

I currently have two relations table `A(url varchar(30))` and table `B(url varchar(30))` and I would like to write an assertion so that it is impossible to insert into table B if that element already exists in table A. How do I do this in JDBC? If it's not possible to use assertions, how would I make something similar happen?

EDIT: Ok, so I've read that it's not possible to create an assertion using postgresql; thus, my question is now, how would I do something similar using the constraints of Postgresql and JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is effectively a negative foreign key constraint, which isn't directly supported. You can implement this constraint using a PL/PgSQL `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger function that tests the condition.

See [PL/PgSQL trigger procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the Pg docs.

You'll probably need to use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation mode to handle races where one transaction inserts into `B` while the other inserts into `A`. You'll need the improved `serializable` isolation support in 9.1/9.2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is not  typo, perhaps 'JDBM' should be 'JDBC'?

For MapDB (aka JDBM4) there is plan to implement   map modification listeners, which would handle similar situations. There is no functionality like this in JDBM3.

For now I would recommend not to use assertions and check it in your code.

Comment: Thanks.  That should be JDBC